# Why do I need to parse JSON object from jQuery.get()?

Tags: jquery, json

In my javascript, I have a jQuery ajax get request:

```
    $.get(uri, callback_function, 'json');
```

In firebug, I can see the response header:

```
 Content-Type   application/json
```

the response content:

```
{ "status": true, "data": "my test output" }
```

There is even a JSON tab in Net -> XHR which shows the returned data pretty-printed.

However, why in my callback function do I need to parse the data I get?

```
function callback_function(data) {
    console.log(data); // { "status": true, "data": "my test output" } 
                                    //  (printed in black)
    console.log(data.status); // undefined
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);   // why is this needed?? 
    console.log(parsedData); //  Object { status=true, data="my test output"} 
                                                //  (printed in colours)
    console.log(parsedData.status); // true
}
```

From the documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
      jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
      dataType  Type: String
      The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Since I am both expecting and getting a JSON object (see HTTP response header), why do I need to parse what appears to be a mere string?

Comment: Good question. jQuery should do this automatically for you. To be clear: JSON needs to be parsed since it is just text, but with the right content type, jQuery does that automatically.

Comment: Its batter to use $.ajax method with dataType: json

Comment: I am stuck with an older version of jQuery, so it might be a bug in the library.  But I tried as Harsh Sanghani suggested, and I don't encounter this bug (?) using $.ajax(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is just a string, basically, since you then need to parse it to convert it into a javascript object.

You can see it in the debugger pretty formatted as I expect the debugger is also parsing it for you, since showing a long string would be less useful.

So, you parse so you can use the result you get in the language that you need, in this case, in javascript.

Comment: However, jQuery should do this automatically with the right content type set.